# How to create a sequence column for repeated values?

Tags: r

I have a df that is created like so:

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
count <- c(2, 4, 6, 10)
data <- data.frame(ID, count)
data <- data[rep(1:nrow(data), data$count),]
print(data)
```

I want to have another column that essentially prints the sequence of the count? 
I'm not sure how best to describe what I'm getting at basically I want it to look like the following output:

```
    ID count sequence
1    1     2        1
1.1  1     2        2
2    2     4        1
2.1  2     4        2
2.2  2     4        3
2.3  2     4        4
3    3     6        1
3.1  3     6        2
3.2  3     6        3
3.3  3     6        4
3.4  3     6        5
3.5  3     6        6
4    4    10        1
4.1  4    10        2
4.2  4    10        3
4.3  4    10        4
4.4  4    10        5
4.5  4    10        6
4.6  4    10        7
4.7  4    10        8
4.8  4    10        9
4.9  4    10       10
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data$sequence <- unlist(lapply( with(data, rle(count)$lengths), seq_len))
data
   ID count sequence
1    1     2        1
1.1  1     2        2
2    2     4        1
2.1  2     4        2
2.2  2     4        3
2.3  2     4        4
3    3     6        1
3.1  3     6        2
3.2  3     6        3
3.3  3     6        4
3.4  3     6        5
3.5  3     6        6
4    4    10        1
4.1  4    10        2
4.2  4    10        3
4.3  4    10        4
4.4  4    10        5
4.5  4    10        6
4.6  4    10        7
4.7  4    10        8
4.8  4    10        9
4.9  4    10       10
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rowid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
data %>% 
    mutate(sequence = rowid(ID))
#     ID count sequence
#1    1     2        1
#1.1  1     2        2
#2    2     4        1
#2.1  2     4        2
#2.2  2     4        3
#2.3  2     4        4
#3    3     6        1
#3.1  3     6        2
#3.2  3     6        3
#3.3  3     6        4
#3.4  3     6        5
#3.5  3     6        6
#4    4    10        1
#4.1  4    10        2
#4.2  4    10        3
#4.3  4    10        4
#4.4  4    10        5
#4.5  4    10        6
#4.6  4    10        7
#4.7  4    10        8
#4.8  4    10        9
#4.9  4    10       10
```

If it is based on the 'count' column

```
data %>%
     mutate(sequence = rowid(count))
```

---

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
data$sequence <- with(data, ave(seq_along(ID), ID, FUN = seq_along))
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! It was so simple, but my mind was just blank. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `by`:

```
data$sequence <- 
unlist(with(data, by(ID, ID, seq_along)), use.names=FALSE)
```

or `data.table`:

```
data.table::data.table(data)[, sequence := seq_len(.N), by=ID][]
```